# Generate Unique Values Each Time A Function Is Called?

Tags: haskell

How do I make a Haskell function which generates a unique value every time it's called over the course of a program?

One idea is:

```hs
incrementInteger :: IO (Integer)
incrementInteger = -- ...
```

such that it increments each time it is called over the course of the program (no matter which thread it's called from, etc).

```hs
incrementIngeter
=> 0

incrementInteger
=> 1

incrementInteger
=> 2
```

That said, the only property I care about for this function "no matter what, the value is unique each time it is called".  How to do this?

**EDIT:** It looks like [Data.UUID](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID-V5.html) provides this via `generatedNamed`.

Comment: If you really, truly need this to be I/O, you could maybe implement this in C with the FFI?

Comment: "EDIT: It looks like Data.UUID provides this via `generatedNamed`." Careful. The one you linked is UUID v5, which means the number is based on the inputs you give it. It will only give you unique results if you give it unique namespace and/or object parameters each time. I don't think that's what you want. If you want to use UUID, try [UUID v1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID-V1.html), which uses your MAC address and a timestamp. Or just use the [time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) package to get an actual timestamp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `base` package offers [`newUnique`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Unique.html#v:newUnique) for this purpose. (N.B. these values will be unique within a single program run, but not necessarily across runs.)

Answer (score 5):

I would probably solve this using `State Integer` at first—or if the code is already in `IO`, then by writing a wrapper for `ReaderT (IORef Integer) IO`. It’s easier to understand code that makes it explicit which functions can access and modify the value, compared to a global counter.

However, if all else fails and you really do want it to be program-global, the usual *unsafe* way to do it in GHC Haskell is:

```
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

-- A global mutable counter
-- The NOINLINE is critical to ensure the counter is unique
counter :: IORef Integer
counter = unsafePerformIO (newIORef 0)
{-# NOINLINE counter #-}

-- Atomically increment the counter and return its current value
next :: IO Integer
next = atomicModifyIORef' counter (\ x -> (x + 1, x))
```

`Data.Unique` in `base` uses this implementation under the hood, but does not provide access to the underlying integer. There are also various packages on Hackage providing similar unique ID generation—GUIDs, UUIDs, &c.

Comment: But why roll your own when it already comes standard with the compiler?

Comment: @DanielWagner: If indeed the *only* property that matters is that the value is unique, then `Data.Unique` is perfectly fine. (Heck, even `IORef ()` would work for that.) If you want to `Show`, serialise, or otherwise manipulate the identifier, you need an implementation that exposes those capabilities.